# Ways to set positional parameters in bash

Tags: bash

From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin

> ```
> set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [-o option-name] [argument …]
> set [+abefhkmnptuvxBCEHPT] [+o option-name] [argument …]
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `--` If no arguments follow this option, then the positional parameters are unset. Otherwise, the positional parameters are set to the
>   arguments, even if some of them begin with a ‘-’.
>
> `-` Signal the end of options, cause all remaining arguments to be assigned to the positional parameters. The -x and -v options are
>   turned off. If there are no arguments, the positional parameters
>   remain unchanged.
>
> Using ‘+’ rather than ‘-’ causes these options to be turned off. The
>   options can also be used upon invocation of the shell. The current set
>   of options may be found in $-.
>
> The remaining N arguments are positional parameters and are assigned,
>   in order, to $1, $2, … $N. The special parameter # is set to N.

It seems that there are three ways to set the position parameters:

```
set -- argument
set - argument
set argument
```

What are their differences?

Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, [POSIX specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set) leave `set - ...` unspecified and only cover `set -- ...`.  Beyond that, I don't know what you're asking.  The difference is the number of hyphens.  The difference in *effect* (if any) is **precisely described in the very document you've quoted.**  Their differences metaphysically or in general semantics is outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference between `--` and `-` is that when `-` is used, the `-x` and `-v` options are also unset.

```
$ set -vx
$ echo "$-"
himvxBHs                # The options -v and -x are set.

$ set - a b c
$ echo "$-  <>  $@"     # The -x and -v options are turned off.
himBHs  <>  a b c
```

That's the usual way in which shells accepted the `-`, however, in POSIX, this option is "unspecified":

> If the first argument is '-', the results are unspecified.

The difference between `set --` and plain `set` is quite commonly used.
It is clearly explained in the manual:

> --      If no arguments follow this option, then the positional parameters are unset.  Otherwise,  the positional parameters are set to the args, even if some of them begin with a -.

The -- signals the "end of options" and any argument that follows even if it start with a - will be used as a Positional argument.

```
$ set -- -a -b -e -f arg1
$ echo "$@"
-a -b -e -f arg1
```

Instead:

```
$ set -a -b -e -f arg1
$ echo "$@"
arg1
```

But also some shell options have changed.

Not using any of - or -- will allow the setting of set options with variables that expand to options names (even if quoted):

```
$ echo "$-"
himBHs

$ a='-f'
$ set "$a"

$ echo "$-"
fhimBHs
```

Answer (score 9):

The difference between `set argument` and `set -- argument` is common to many other commands.

You sometimes have an argument that starts with a `-`, but you can't actually use it because the command thinks (because it starts with `-`) that it's actually a command option.

What the `--` says is effectively: "Enough! everything that follows, even if it starts with `-`, is an actual argument".

Usually (according to manual pages) a lone `-` is equivalent to `--` for this purpose.

**Example**

You might use:

```
set -- -a -b file1 file2
```

to set `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$4` to `-a`, `-b`, `file1` and `file2` respectively. The `--` isn't stored - it's just an indicator; without it, the `-a` and `-b` would be interpreted as possible option for the `set` command itself.