# Are variables like $0 and $1 shell/environment variables?

Tags: shell

There are variables in the shell like `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, `$?`, etc.

I tried to print the shell and environment variables using the following command:

```
set
```

But these variables were not in the list.

So basically these variables are not considered to be shell/environment variables, right? (even though to output them, you have to precede them with a `$`, like you do with shell/environment variables)

Comment: The positional parameters are not variables. You cannot `export 3` to turn `$3` into an environment variable. You cannot `unset 3`; and you cannot assign `$3` a new value using `3=val`.

Answer (score 25):

Variables are one of three distinct varieties of parameters in shell.

1. A *variable* is a parameter whose name is a valid shell identifier; starts with `_` or a letter, followed by zero or more letters, numbers or `_`.
2. The *positional* parameters are the numbered parameters `$1`, `$2`, ...
3. The *special* parameters all have single-character names, and aside from `$0`, they are all various punctuation characters.

`set` only displays the shell's variables.

A subset of the shell variables are the environment variables, whose values are either inherited from the environment when the shell starts up, or are created by setting the `export` attribute on a valid name.

Comment: Note that `set` displays all parameters in `zsh` (not $1, $2... but $*, $@) and the functions in bash and bosh. Some shells like ksh93 and  older versions of dash output env vars that were not mapped to shell variables. (`env 1=foo ksh -c set` would print `1=foo`)

Answer (score 11):

## Environment Variables vs Positional Parameters

Before we begin discussing `$INTEGER` type of variables, we need to understand what they really are and how they differ from environment variables.Variables such as `$INTEGER` are called positional parameters. This is described in the POSIX (Portable Operating System Interface) standard, [section 2.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) (emphasis mine):

> 6. The shell executes a function (see Function Definition Command), built-in (see Special Built-In Utilities), executable file, or script, **giving the names of the arguments as positional parameters numbered 1 to n, and the name of the command (or in the case of a function within a script, the name of the script) as the positional parameter numbered 0** (see Command Search and Execution).

By contrast, variables such as `$HOME` and `$PATH` are environment variables. Their definition is described in [section 8 of the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08):

> Environment variables defined in this chapter affect the operation of multiple utilities, functions, and applications. There are other environment variables that are of interest only to specific utilities. Environment variables that apply to a single utility only are defined as part of the utility description.

Notice their description. Positional parameters are meant to appear in front of a command, i.e. `command positional_arg_1 positional_arg_2...`. They are meant to be provided by user to tell command what specifically to do. When you do `echo 'Hello' 'World'`, it will print out  the `Hello` and `World` strings, because these are positional parameters to `echo` - the things you want `echo` to operate on. And `echo` is built such that it understands positional parameters as strings to be printed (unless they're one of the optional flags like `-n` ). If you do this with different command it might not understand what `Hello` and `World` is because perhaps it expects a number. Notice that positional parameters are not "inherited" - a child process does not know about positional parameters of the parent unless explicitly passed to the child process. Often you see positional parameters being passed with wrapper scripts - the ones that maybe check for already existing instance of a command or add additional positional parameters to the real command that will be called.

By contrast, environment variables  are meant to affect multiple programs. They are *environment* variables, because they're set outside of the program itself (more on this below). Certain environment variables such as `HOME` or `PATH` have specific format, specific meaning, and they'll mean the same to each program. `HOME` variable will mean same to either external utility like `/usr/bin/find` or your shell ( and consequently to a script ) - it's the home directory of the username under which process runs. Notice  that environmental variables can be used to account for specific command behavior, for instance `UID` environment variable can be used to check whether the script runs with root privileges or not and branch to specific actions accordingly. Environment variables are inheritable - child processes get copy of parent's environment. See also [If processes inherit the parent's environment, why do we need export?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/130985/85039)

In short, the main distinction is that environment variables are set outside of the command and not meant to be varied (usually), while positional parameters are things that are meant to be processed by the command and they change.

---

## Not just shell concepts

What I've noticed from comments is that you're mixing up terminal and shell, and would really recommend you read about [real terminals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/359038/85039) that once upon a time were physical devices. Nowadays, the "terminal" that we're typically referring to, that window with black background and green text is actually software, a process. Terminal is a program that runs a shell, while shell is also a program but the one that reads what you type in to execute ( that is, if it is interactive shell; non-interactive shells are scripts and `sh -c 'echo foo'` types of invocations). More on shells [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/85039).

This is an important distinction, but also important to recognize that terminal is a program and therefore adheres to the same rules of environment and positional parameters. Your `gnome-terminal` when started will look at your `SHELL` environment variable, and spawn the appropriate default shell for you, unless you specify some other command with `-e`. Let's say I changed my default shell to `ksh`  - gnome-terminal will then spawn `ksh` instead of `bash`. That's also an example of how environment is used by programs. If I explicitly tell `gnome-terminal` with `-e` to run specific shell - it will do it, but it won't be permanent. By contrast, environment is meant to be mostly unaltered (more on that later).

So as you can see, environment and positional variables are both properties of a process/command, not just shell. When it comes to shell scripts, they also follow the model that was set by C programming language. Take for instance the C `main` function which typically looks like

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

, where  `argc` is number of command-line arguments and `argv` is effectively array of command-line parameters, and then there's `environ` function ( on Linux that's `man -e 7 environ` ) to access things like user's home directory path, list of directories in `PATH` where we can look for executables, etc. Shell scripts are also modeled in the similar way.  In shell terminology, we have positional parameters `$1`, `$2` and so forth, while `$#` is number of positional parameters. What about `$0` ? That's the name of the executable itself, which is again also modeled from C programming language - `argv[0]` would be name of your C "executable". And this is fairly true for [most programming and scripting languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_argument_parsing).

#### Interactive vs Non-interactive shells

One of the things I've already hinted is the distinction between [interactive and non-interactive shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50665/85039). The prompt where you type in commands - that's interactive, it interacts with the user. By contrast when you have a shell script or you run `bash -c''` that's non-interactive.

And this is where distinction becomes important. The shell that you run already is a process, which was spawned with positional parameters ( for `bash` login shell is one "...whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option." ([reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) ) )

By contrast, scripts and shells launched with `-c` option can take advantage of `$1` and `$2` arguments.  For instance,

```
$ bash -c 'echo $1; stat $2' sh 'Hello World' /etc/passwd
Hello World
  File: '/etc/passwd'
  Size: 2913        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 6035604     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-08-12 14:48:37.125879962 -0600
Modify: 2017-08-12 14:48:37.125879962 -0600
Change: 2017-08-12 14:48:37.137879811 -0600
 Birth: -
```

Notice that I've also used `sh` there, because small quirk of `-c` option is to take first positional parameter and assign it to `$0`, unlike typically being a name of the program.

Another thing that is important to notice is that positional parameters are what I call "framable".  Notice how, we first launched `bash` with its own positional parameters, but those positional parameters became parameters to `echo` and `stat`. And each program understands it in its own way. If we gave to `stat` a string `Hello World` and there's no file `Hello World` it would produce an error; `bash` treats it just as a simple string but `stat` expects that string to be an existing filename.  By contrast,  all programs would agree that environment variable `HOME` is a directory ( unless the programmer coded it in an unreasonable way).

---

## Can we mess around with environment variables and positional parameters ?

Technically, we can mess around with both, but we *shouldn't* mess around with environment variables, while we often have to provide positional parameters. We can run commands in shell with prepending a variable, for instance:

```
$ hello=world bash -c 'echo $hello'
world
```

We can also place variables into environment simply using `export variable=value` from within shell or script. Or we can run a command with completely empty environment with `env -c command arg1 arg2`. However, typically it is not recommended to mess around with environment, especially using upper-case variables or overwriting already existing environment variables. Notice that's recommended although not a standard.

For positional parameters, the way to set them is obvious, just prepend them to the command, but also there are ways to [set them other wise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378580/85039),  as well as change the list of those parameters via `shift` command.

In conclusion, purpose of these two is different, and they exist for a reason. I hope people gained some insight from this answer, and it was fun reading it just as it was for me to write this answer.

---

## Note on set command

The `set` command, according to manual behaves like so (from bash manual, emphasis added):

> Without options, the name and value of each **shell variable** are  displayed  in a format that can be reused as input for setting or resetting the  currently-set  variables.

In other words `set` looks at variables specific to shell, some of which happen to be in the environment, for example `HOME`. By contrast commands like `env` and `printenv` look at actual environment variable with which a command runs. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5657113/3701431).

Comment: " In interactive shell, you cannot reference $1, $2, and so forth. " is there a direct reference for this? I have run into strange cases where these are set in an interactive shell environment and I am not sure if this would be considered 'non-standard' or not.

Comment: @user5359531 Honestly, I'm not quite sure where I got that from. Probably because back when I posted the answer in 2017 I probably referenced that you can't do something like `1="foo"` but later I found out that by POSIX definition a "word"  ( that is a name of an object such as variable or function ) cannot start with a digit ( see a [question I posted on the topic](https://askubuntu.com/q/977908/295286) ).  Positional parameters apparently are exception to this rule.

Comment: @user5359531 I've removed the part of the answer, since it's not particularly accurate. You can reference `$1`, `$2` and so forth in interactive shell, and in fact that's done with `set` command, often to get around `/bin/sh` limitation of not having arrays.  Thanks for bringing this up to my attention. I'm also going to edit the answer over the next few days, since it needs a bit of extra polish and an update.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The problem I am having is that with `conda`, when you run `source conda/bin/activate`, it checks for whether `$1`, `$2`, etc., are set, in order to determine if it was run as a script with arguments or not. This ends up breaking on systems that have those set in the interactive environment for some reason. I am hoping to figure out if this non-standard behavior is a flaw in the system for setting these variables in the interactive environment, or on the program for using them to determine if it was run as a script.

Comment: @user5359531 I'd suggest you file a bug report to `conda` developers or to whoever is the original author of such script, as checking for `${N}` parameters is definitely the wrong way to go.  There are questions on the same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683279/how-to-detect-if-a-script-is-being-sourced) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214079/differentiating-between-running-and-being-sourced-in-a-bash-shell-script), and more or less portable way is to check if `${0}` is same as script name, while `bash` actually has environment variable for that purpose

Answer (score 5):

The `$1, $2, $3, ..., ${10}, ${11}` variables are called positional parameters and are covered in the bash manual section `3.4.1`

> **3.4.1 Positional Parameters**
>
> A positional parameter is a parameter denoted by one or more digits, other than the single digit 0. Positional parameters are assigned from the shell’s arguments when it is invoked, and may be reassigned using the set builtin command. Positional parameter N may be referenced as ${N}, or as $N when N consists of a single digit. Positional parameters may not be assigned to with assignment statements. The set and shift builtins are used to set and unset them (see Shell Builtin Commands). The positional parameters are temporarily replaced when a shell function is executed (see Shell Functions).
>
> When a positional parameter consisting of more than a single digit is expanded, it must be enclosed in braces.

As for `$?` and `$0`, these *special parameters* are covered in the very next section `3.4.2`

> **3.4.2 Special Parameters**
>
> The shell treats several parameters specially. These parameters may only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.
>
> ...
>
> **?**
>
> ($?) Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.
>
> **0**
>
> ($0) Expands to the name of the shell or shell script. This is set at shell initialization. If Bash is invoked with a file of commands (see Shell Scripts), $0 is set to the name of that file. If Bash is started with the -c option (see Invoking Bash), then $0 is set to the first argument after the string to be executed, if one is present. Otherwise, it is set to the filename used to invoke Bash, as given by argument zero.

Answer (score 5):

`$1`, `$2`... are *positional parameters*, they are not variables, let alone environment variables.

In Bourne-like shell terminology, `$something` is called *parameter* expansion (also covers `${something#pattern}` and more in some shells like `${array[x]}`, `${param:offset}`, `${x:|y}` and many more expansion operators).

There are different sorts of parameters:

- *variables* like `$foo`, `$PATH`
- positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`... the arguments that your script received)
- other special parameters like `$0`, `$-`, `$#`, `$*`, `$@`, `$$`, `$!`, `$?`...

variable names in Bourne like shells must start with one alphabetical character (any recognised by the locale, or limited to a-zA-Z depending on the shell) and underscore and followed by zero or more alphanumerical characters or underscores.

Depending on the shell, variables can have different types (scalar, array, hash) or given certain attributes (read-only, exported, lower case...).

Some of those variables are created by the shell or have special meaning to the shell (like `$OPTIND`, `$IFS`, `$_`...)

Shell variables that have the *export* attribute are automatically exported as *environment variables* to the commands that the shell executes.

Environment variable is a concept separate from shell variables. Exporting a shell variable is not the only way to pass an environment variable to the execution of a command.

```
VAR=foo
export VAR
printenv VAR
```

will pass a `VAR` environment variable to the `printenv` command (which we're telling to print its content), but you can also do:

```
env VAR=foo printenv VAR
```

or:

```
perl -e '$ENV{VAR}="foo"; exec "printenv", "VAR"'
```

for instance.

Environment variables can have any name (can contain any character but `=` and can even be empty). It's not a good idea to give a name that is not compatible to that of a Bourne-like shell variable name to an environment variable, but it's possible:

```
$ env '#+%=whatever' printenv '#+%'
whatever
```

Shells will map the environment variables that they *receive* to shell variables only for those environment variables whose name are valid shell variables (and in some shells ignore some special ones like `$IFS`).

So, while you'd be able to pass a `1` environment variable to a command:

```
$ env '1=whatever' printenv 1
whatever
```

That doesn't mean that calling a shell with that environment variable would set the value of the `$1` parameter:

```
$ env '1=whatever' sh -c 'echo "$1"' script-name foo bar
foo
```

Answer (score 3):

No, these are parameters of the script. For example if you call your script like:

```
mynicescript.sh one two three
```

then inside the script, there will be these parameters available as

```
$1 = one
$2 = two
$3 = three
```

and the $0 is the name of the script itself.

So when you're outside the script, these variables aren't available (except $0, which displays /bin/bash - the shell itself).

Comment: *"So when you're outside the script, these variables aren't available"* What do you mean by *"outside the script"*, because I can see the values of these variables in my terminal.

Comment: @user7681202: Which ones can you see in your terminal?  `$0` will point to your current terminal process (likely bash) and `$?` is simply the exit code of the last process.

Comment: I tried to run the `gnome-terminal` with arguments (`gnome-terminal Hello World`). I could see `$0`, but I could not see `$1` and `$2`.

Comment: @Jesse_b Thank you, I've added the content of $0 into the answer.

Comment: @user7681202 The gnome-terminal isn't shell, it's terminal emulator (like xterm, konsole etc.). The shell runs inside the terminal and it can be bash/sh/zsh/tcsh and many more. The script is executable file with proper header (like #!/bin/bash) and content interpretable by the shell specified in the mask. It usually uses suffix .sh

Comment: @user7681202 you're confusing `gnome-terminal` with `shell` as Jaroslav explained. `gnome-terminal` is one program, shell is another. `gnome-terminal` runs shell. Arguments that you give to `gnome-terminal` will have those `Hello` and `World` as arguments to itself. And gnome-terminal will start  shell with its own positional parameters. `$1` and `$2` are really meant for non-interactive shells, i.e. for scripts and things like `bash -c 'commad 1; command 2'`

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy You are right, I mixed these things. Is there a way to run a shell with arguments with a terminal, I tried the following inside a `gnome-terminal` (`bash Hello World`), but I got an error (it thought that I am running a script called "Hello").

Comment: @user7681202 technically speaking, yes there are ways to do that. `bash` manual shows that syntax for `bash` is `bash [options] [command_string | file]` , so if you have a script files called `Hello` and `World` you can easily do `gnome-terminal -e 'bash Hello World'` , and bash will execute them, because that's how it's built to understand positional parameters.  It won't treat them as text strings. BUT you could also do `hello=world gnome-terminal -e 'bash' ` and you can access `$hello` variable from environment. It's a convoluted topic, and I'll add more details on it to my answer later

Comment: @user7681202 updated my answer. Let me know if you have any other questions.